# See if user in ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I am trying to see if the current user is in the `collaborators` m2m field, but keep getting an error saying:

`Cannot query "John Doe": Must be "Company" instance.`

Could someone help me out with the conditional statement please?

**models.py:**

```
class MyUser():
    name = ...
    email = ...

class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, null=True,
                             related_name='company_owner',
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, blank=True, 
                                           related_name='company_collaborators')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

**views.py:**

```
def company_dash(request, username):
    user = request.user
    company = get_object_or_404(
        Company, Q(is_active=True), username=username)

    # NEED HELP HERE PLEASE
    if company.user == user or company.collaborators.filter(company_collaborators=user).exists():
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full docs is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

You can use

```
if company.user == user or company.collaborators.filter(collaborators=user):
```

or

```
if company.user == user or company.collaborators.filter(id=user.id):
```

I think there is no need to add `.exists()` due to `filter(collaborators=user)` returns list that to be evaluated to be `False` if empty.

Comment: I am getting an error `Manager isn't accessible via Company instances` for both methods.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I changed a bit, So it might work now.